# Generating callstack from inside system call

Tags: c++, linux, yocto

I have a scenario where a thread sometimes freezes for a c++ application on an arm based yocto/poky linux system. It stops somewhere within the clock_nanosleep system call.

I can generate core files using gcore and attach with gdb, but it only shows me the usermode part of the callstack which ends at the software interrupt.

Is there a way to find out where the thread actually is within the kernel, possible from a coredump?

Edit: This is the code of the method call. The variable t is on the stack.

```
do {
   ret = clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0,  &t, &t);
} while (ret == EINTR);
```

Regards

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that only the application freezes? If that's the case you can probably use `strace` to see if the system call returns or if that's not enough use something more powerful like [systemtap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/).

Comment: "It stops somewhere within the clock_nanosleep system call." I mean yes, that's the point of that syscall

Comment: You might have a deadlock or race condition. You'll need to post the relevant thread code before the sleep.

Comment: For clarification: It spends more than a full minute in clock_nanosleep. It isn't just there accidentally while I dump. The application doesn't freeze, only one or two threads do and all of them in clock_nanosleep. Yes, I checked that the input times are small ( 5 ms each ).

Comment: Another guess in the dark: do you initialize all fields in the struct or could it be that some use uninitialized data? Otherwise I fear you'll have to go into kernel debugging, a rather painful process.

Comment: Don't waste your time debugging the kernel. The bug is in your code.

Comment: @ErkiA Most definitely, but if getting a kernel stacktrace was easy, it could help understanding what the bug is. Seeing that Desperado works on embedded, it could also be some weird corner case.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly I also see from comments, that he is using threads and I'm 90% sure, that's where the bug is hidden. The other 9.99% is an invalid use of clock_nanosleep() function.

Comment: I added the method call to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get kernel call stack from user-space. Even if it was possible, it would hardly help you in debugging your problem.

Make sure, that you accidentally don't share the structs passed to clock_nanosleep() between threads, that all the errors returned by the functions are handled and reported, that you are using correct clock source (CLOCK_MONOTONIC probably) and that you are using clock_nanosleep() as described in [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_nanosleep.2.html)